# How to handle DNS at the firewall

Tags: domain-name-system, routing, reverse-proxy, port-forwarding

I'm running in to a mental roadblock trying to figure this one out.

We have a Juniper firewall at our office and we do a lot of port forwarding to reach internal services that we need to access from the outside. For example, our build server lives at `http://machine1:8190` so we forward all requests on that port at the firewall to the internal machine on the same port.

Instead, I want to access the build server at `http://build.mydomain.com`. Internally I have the DNS setup to point to our nginx server running a reverse proxy so that all internal requests for `http://build.mydomain.com` get proxied to `http://machine1:8190`. Where I'm struggling is figuring out how I can get my external requests (from outside the office) to work the same way. If I setup DNS to point to our public IP of our office, what do I need to configure at the firewall? Obviously the requests comes in through `:80` but I have another port forwarding rules that uses that port. Do I just need to point the firewall DNS at our internal DNS server? I'm just not sure what the right approach is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider three options:

- Use port 443 for access to internal services. Forward this to `nginx` from the firewall and have `nginx` do appropriate authentication before forwarding.  (This would be my preferred option, as I would require authentication for remote access.)
- Have the current server for port 80 forward request to `nginx`.  `apache/apache2` has the appropriate proxy capabilities.  Many other web server have similar capablities.
- Have `nginx` forward web traffic to the existing server.  You already have it forwarding.  This would just be one more forwarding rule (perhaps the default rule.)

To support this you may want additional DNS aliases for the external IP address.